# I am trying to create a lookup function without creating a pivot

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, lookup

I want to get a sum of the cells in column B with 2 criteria (Which type [WIND or WATER], and it's location [e.g VIC = 1-7, NSW = 15-17])So i would hope that cell F4 becomes 78 and G4 becomes 14.

Additional notes: I am pasting in the raw data and the rows are not always set.

Example:

[image: Example]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Take a look at the `SUMIFS` function.

Comment: Since you will be pasting the data each time into the web page, can the layout of the data be changes such that B15:B22 would be pasted into C2:C9?  This would make column B the wind results, and column C the Water results and would reduce the repeated information in column A as to location codes since it would only need to be displayed once.

Answer (score 0):

for F4 use the following

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9,">=1",$A$2:$A$9,"<=7")
```

For G4 use the following:

```
=SUMIFS($B$15:$B$22,$A$15:$A$22,">=1",$A$15:$A$22,"<=7")
```

for single entry ranges like F16 use the following

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$9,20,$B$2:$B$9)
```

and G16 uses:

```
=SUMIF($A$15:$A$22,20,$B$15:$B$22)
```

There are other possible solutions depending on how complex you want to make the formula.  You can also make your life a little easier if you set your upper and lower limiting boundaries for a region in their own separate cells without the excess text.

Comment: My problem is that i will be pasting in the raw data to lookup each time and the rows can change. Sorry i should have mentioned this in the original question. (My first question on this site).